# Binary archives of OpenJDK for ubuntu

Tags: package-management, java, openjdk

My goal is to have multiple version of java 6 and multiple version of java 7 installed on my ubuntu in order to do some tests with different versions of java.

I found instructions to install oracle jdk/jre manually and it works fine.
However I don't know where to find archives for openjdk for ubuntu.

Are they available anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Getting the jdk from oracle here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html is essentially the same as from elsewhere. Oracle doesn't seem to want you to get the tar.gz of the jdk/jre without first accepting their license agreement. As far as I can tell they have managed to successfully remove the old archives from the web. Heres the geneaology showing the links between the jdk and openjdk [image]